# How do I make my lxqt faster?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a windows and a Linux OS running on the same PC. Earlier I used to use only Linux since windows was too damn slow, but ever since I have modified the settings of my windows and dropped the animation, tweaked a bit with registry and page size, I feel windows to be a lot more faster and able to multitask more than Linux even though the unused ram on my Linux is much more than windows.

Are there any settings that I can tweak to make my lxqt faster?

Comment: What are you running ON and what are you running in it?  I have a Windows 10 Pro Host on an i7 laptop with 16 GB of memory and an NVMe SSD drive. Plenty fast. I have 3 machines running now (VMware Workstation): 1 Windows 7, 1 Kali, 1 Ubuntu and the machines are plenty fast as well. 12 GB of RAM used, 4 available. No slowdowns.

Comment: I have a very slow hardware, 7th gen i3, 4gb ram, an hdd, I do a dual boot. Used to prefer Linux very much since it was very less problematic to set up for dev, but ever since I have started using windows for my intern I feel windows can be optimised for much better performance. I also think it's application dependent, like vscode and intellij hangs more on Linux than windows